# Не могу создать папку в папке VS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

При попытке создать папку в другой папке VS, вместо создания новый папки, программа присоединяет ее к старой. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема ушла, когда я создал внутри изначальной папки файл, а после стал добавлять внутрь папки новые папки.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно зайти в параметры/функции/проводник(setting/features/explorer) и убрать галочку Compact Folders